# Why aren't static fields enforced to be readonly in readonly structs?

Tags: c#, struct

```
readonly struct Read{

    readonly int j; //not ok without readonly
    static int Sj;  //ok

}
```

Why aren't static fields enforced to be readonly in readonly structs, while instance fields are obliged to be readonly in readonly structs?

Comment: I would assume that it is because a static instance (if made public) is targeted without an instance of `Read` and _cannot_ be targeted via an instance of `Read`. In other words, `Sj` lives outside of the scope of a single `Read` instance...therefore it can't be constrained to the same rules as instance fields.

Comment: Okay, so you suggest that the instance is Forced to be readonly, not the type.

Comment: No, the type IS forced to be readonly, but a static field exists as a single "instance" across all instances of `Read`. As a result, how could you constrain it to be readonly and still usable? It needs the flexibility to choose to be readonly or not readonly.

Comment: Well, I see what you mean. So It is like the instance readonly field can at least be different for each instance which would noy be the case with static fields.

Comment: Correct, it is the same principle. So as a result, the language designers decided not to constrain a static fields in readonly structs to readonly, which I would argue was a wise choice.

Comment: There isn't even a need to constrain it. `readonly struct` was invented for performance reasons mainly, and that applies to instances of the struct, not `static` fields